# How to configure Spring with Neo4j Ha cluster?

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, high-availability, spring-data-neo4j

I have clustered 3 instances of Neo4j Enterprise Edition (v1.8.2) on 3 different machine with Ha and they are working good as of now (when accessing through Ha front end url).
I wanted to know how can I configure my Spring configuration (applicationContext.xml) in order to use **Ha front end url** , which target to 3 instances of neo4j server in backend.
I went through this [link](http://lists.neo4j.org/pipermail/user/2011-November/013871.html). which describe below lines:

`<bean id="haDatabase" class="org.neo4j.kernel.HighlyAvailableGraphDatabase" destroy-method="shutdown">

    <constructor-arg index="0" value="target/config-test"/>

    <constructor-arg index="1">

<map>

<entry key="ha.server_id" value="1"/>

            <entry key="ha.server" value="192.168.1.10:6001"/>

            <entry key="ha.coordinators" value="192.168.1.10:2181,192.168.1.9:2182,192.168.1.8:2183"/>

</map>

</constructor-arg>

</bean>

<neo4j:config graphDatabaseService="haDatabase"/>`

I am exactly not getting, how and why should I re-configure the **server_id** and **coordinators** here, which I have already done for all neo4j server configuration.

**Update #1**

After applying above configuration, and kept all three instances running with Ha proxy. I get below logs in Eclipse and get hanged over there while debugging my application ...

`14:29:13.220 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG neo4j - Read HA server:192.168.1.10:6001 (for machineID 1) from zoo keeper

14:29:13.227 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG neo4j - Read HA server:192.168.1.8:6003 (for machineID 3) from zoo keeper
14:29:13.232 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG neo4j - Read HA server:192.168.1.9:6002 (for machineID 2) from zoo keeper
14:29:13.239 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG neo4j - Writing at flush-requested: -6
14:29:13.268 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG neo4j - getMaster 3 based on [MachineInfo[ID:1, sequence:29, last tx:97, server:(192.168.1.10, 6001), master for last tx:3], MachineInfo[ID:2, sequence:30, last tx:97, server:(192.168.1.9, 6002), master for last tx:3], MachineInfo[ID:3, sequence:31, last tx:97, server:(192.168.1.8, 6003), master for last tx:3]]
14:29:13.333 [pool-13-thread-1] DEBUG neo4j - org.neo4j.kernel.ha.zookeeper.ZooClient$WatcherImpl@169a0c5, Fri Aug 09 14:29:13 IST 2013 Got event: WatchedEvent state:SyncConnected type:None path:null (path=null)`

**Update #2**
Another query raised is, I am not using direct Haproxy front end url anywhere in my spring configuration. then what is role Haproxy play in my spring app ? I discussed this with one of my friend, and as per his suggestion there should be some way to use Ha proxy url.

**Update #3**
`<bean id="graphDatabaseService" class="org.springframework.data.neo4j.rest.SpringRestGraphDatabase">

<constructor-arg index="0" value="http://192.168.1.46:81/db/data" />

</bean>`
I have tried above case as well, but what I felt its performance was not upto the mark (*http://192.168.1.46:81* is my haproxy front end url targeting to 3 instances of neo4j server).

any clue, where I am stuck to ? Please help

Comment: You should be good, just using the same coordinators you already have in your server config. As your spring app will probably be the 4th databases server you should provide a server id of **4**. Your spring configured instance is a full member of the HA cluster, not a client or so.

Comment: @MichaelHunger `192.168.1.10:6001` is the instance where I am running my spring app. Over this instance, Server id is 1. rest of instance have id of 2 and 3. and Yes my spring configured instance is full member of the HA cluster. but still not able to run.

Comment: @MichaelHunger can you plz suggest me, how can I use the Ha front end url for above mentioned configuration. e.g. 192.168.1.46:81/db/data target to Neo4j REST interface. Can I used this for HighlyAvailableGraphDatabase ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue resolved, just by implementing below changes in my applicationContext.xml spring configuration:
`<bean id="graphDatabaseService" class="org.neo4j.kernel.HighlyAvailableGraphDatabase" destroy-method="shutdown">

<constructor-arg index="0" value="/opt/build/mydb/graph.db"/>

<constructor-arg index="1">

<map>

      <entry key="ha.server_id" value="1"/>

<entry key="ha.server" value="192.168.1.10:6001"/>

<entry key="ha.coordinators" value="192.168.1.10:2181,192.168.1.9:2182,192.168.1.8:2183"/>

</map>

</constructor-arg>

</bean>

<neo4j:config graphDatabaseService="graphDatabaseService"/>`

As per my understanding, We need to mention at least primary location of graph.db followed by ha configuration with coordinators details.
Would like to thanks Michael for this ([link 1](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/neo4j/spring%2420data%2420and%2420neo4j%2420HA/neo4j/8CH6jLBpujs/_ppxCI5JD30J) and [link 2](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-data-neo4j/blob/master/spring-data-neo4j/src/test/resources/org/springframework/data/neo4j/config/DataGraphNamespaceHandlerTests-external-ha-context.xml)). Appreciated Thanks :)